# How get a list of dependent modules in within some parent module?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, list, module

**Setup:**

Several angularjs modules declared as:

```
angular.module('a', ['a.b']);

angular.module('a.b', ['a.b.c1', 'a.b.c2']);

angular.module('a.b.c1', []);

angular.module('a.b.c2', []);
```

**Question:**

Is there a way to get all children modules from a specific parent module?
I mean something like:

```
angular.module.getChildrenFromParent('a.b');
```

That should return an array of strings or an array of references to the modules `a.b.c1` and `a.b.c2`.

Thanks

**UPDATE**

I know there is [How can I get a list of available modules in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20974726/881286) but it isn't a clean solution and it is a bit of an old answer too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `requires` property of the module object returned (by `angular.module` getter invocation) to get the dependency list.

i.e

```
var dependentModules = angular.module('a.b').requires;
```

This will output an array of strings representing the dependencies `["a.b.c1", "a.b.c2"]`. But note that you can use it only after module has been created otherwise invoking this for a module that has not been created will result in an error. And if you want to go deep just implement a recursive lookup for each dependencies.

**Demo**

```js
angular.module('a.b.c1', []);

angular.module('a.b.c2', []);
angular.module('a.b', ['a.b.c1', 'a.b.c2']);

angular.module('a', ['a.b']);

console.log(angular.module('a.b').requires);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks! I missed that from documentation :(

Comment: @diosney to be frank i have not seen this in documentation, i never found out this property availability in the module object until trying to answer your question. :)